# Set different custom menu items for different user roles

Tags: plugin-development, user-roles, admin-menu, admin-bar, add-menu-page

I have added some custom menu using add-menu_page and it is working perfectly with the default administrator admin bar. But when I log in to different user roles, they are not showing. My question is how to show different menu items for different users.

I have added these codes to my plugin main function.php file

```
function custom_admin_menu()
{
    global $menu, $submenu;
    
    $icon = get_option('cqpim_use_default_icon');
    if(empty($icon)) {
        $adicon = PTO_PLUGIN_URL . '/img/icon.png';
    } else {
        $adicon = '';
    }
    
    // My work
    add_menu_page('My Work', 'My Work', 'read', 'custom-slug', '', $adicon, 28);
    $submenu['custom-slug'][] = array('My Messages', 'manage_options', admin_url().'admin.php?page=pto-messages');
    $submenu['custom-slug'][] = array('All Messages (Admin)', 'manage_options', admin_url().'admin.php?page=pto-messages-admin');
    $submenu['custom-slug'][] = array('My Tasks', 'manage_options', admin_url().'admin.php?page=pto-tasks');
    $submenu['custom-slug'][] = array('My Calender', 'manage_options', admin_url().'admin.php?page=pto-calendar');
    $submenu['custom-slug'][] = array('All Tasks (Admin)', 'manage_options', admin_url().'admin.php?page=pto-alltasks');
    $submenu['custom-slug'][] = array('All Files (Admin)', 'manage_options', admin_url().'admin.php?page=pto-files-admin');
    // Leads
    add_menu_page('Leads', 'Leads', 'read', 'custom-leads', '', $adicon, 29);
    $submenu['custom-leads'][] = array('Leads', 'manage_options', admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=cqpim_lead');
    $submenu['custom-leads'][] = array('Lead Forms', 'manage_options', admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=cqpim_leadform');
    // Clients
    add_menu_page('Leads', 'Clients', 'manage_options', '', '', $adicon, 30);
    $menu[30][2] = admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=cqpim_client';
    // Quotes
    add_menu_page('Quotes', 'Quotes', 'read', 'custom-quotes', '', $adicon, 31);
    $submenu['custom-quotes'][] = array('Quotes', 'manage_options', admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=cqpim_quote');
    $submenu['custom-quotes'][] = array('Quote Forms', 'manage_options', admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=cqpim_forms');
    $submenu['custom-quotes'][] = array('Milestone / Task templates', 'manage_options', admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=cqpim_templates');
    // Projects
    add_menu_page('Projects', 'Projects', 'read', 'custom-projects', '', $adicon, 32);
    $submenu['custom-projects'][] = array('Projects', 'manage_options', admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=cqpim_project');
    $submenu['custom-projects'][] = array('Terms Templates', 'manage_options', admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=cqpim_terms');
    $submenu['custom-projects'][] = array('Milestone / Task Templates', 'manage_options', admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=cqpim_templates');
    $submenu['custom-projects'][] = array('Project Updates', 'manage_options', admin_url().'admin.php?page=pto-updates');
    // Invoices
    add_menu_page('Invoices', 'Invoices', 'read', 'custom-invoices', '', $adicon, 33);
    $submenu['custom-invoices'][] = array('Invoices', 'manage_options', admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=cqpim_invoice');
    $submenu['custom-invoices'][] = array('Recurring Invoices', 'manage_options', admin_url().'admin.php?page=pto-recinvoices');
    // Teams
    add_menu_page('Collaborators', 'Collaborators', 'read', 'custom-teams', '', $adicon, 34);
    $submenu['custom-teams'][] = array('Team Members', 'manage_options', admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=cqpim_teams');
    $submenu['custom-teams'][] = array('Roles & Permissions', 'manage_options', admin_url().'admin.php?page=pto-permissions');
    // Support
    add_menu_page('Support', 'Support', 'read', 'custom-support', '', $adicon, 35);
    $submenu['custom-support'][] = array('Support Tickets', 'manage_options', admin_url().'admin.php?page=pto-tickets');
    $submenu['custom-support'][] = array('FAQ', 'manage_options', admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=cqpim_faq');
    // Settings
    add_menu_page('Settings', 'Settings', 'read', 'custom-settings', '', $adicon, 36);
    $submenu['custom-settings'][] = array('Setting', 'manage_options', admin_url().'admin.php?page=pto-settings');
    $submenu['custom-settings'][] = array('Custom Fields', 'manage_options', admin_url().'admin.php?page=pto-custom-fields');
    $submenu['custom-settings'][] = array('Documentation', 'manage_options',  'http://projectopia.io/');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_admin_menu');
```

This code showing the menu items for the default administrator sidebar but not on the different user dashboard sidebar.

[image: Screenshot]